# Use MQTTNet Server with MQTT.js client

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, tcp, mqtt

I have started an MQTT server just like [this](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/tree/master) example.
This code is hosted in an ASP.Net Core 2.0 application but I have tried console application with no luck.

I have also setup a client using the same demo as above and it connects perfectly. Also an Android client connects fine. But I have placed a MQTT.js client webpage but it will not connect with chrome showing `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

I believe that the problem is with server not supporting web sockets. Because if I start my client with `WS` type it will not connect.

```
var options = new MqttClientOptions
{
    Server = "localhost",
    //ConnectionType = MqttConnectionType.Tcp // Connects
    ConnectionType = MqttConnectionType.Ws    // Does not connect
};
```

Now MQTT.js supports `TCP` as far [this link](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#connect) is telling. But I don't seem to be able to work it.

This is the code in my page javascript:

```
var client = mqtt.connect('tcp://localhost') //Also did mqtt://localhost

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('myTopic')
    client.publish('myTopic', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    console.log(message.toString())
    client.end()
})
```

I want to know how can I make javascript MQTT client to use TCP? (Any other js plugin maybe?) Or alternatively how can I enable WebSockets in MQTTNet.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQTT.js does support both native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets, but if you are embedding it in to a web app it can only use MQTT over Websockets because the browsers sandbox will not allow it to use arbitrary TCP connections.

As for enabling Websockets in the broker I can't see anything obvious in the code so you'll probably have to raise and issue against the github project to ask for details.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer. Just to clear it a bit, you are saying that no js can ever call pure tcp calls because browsers don't allow that?

Comment: Yes, you can only use HTTP or Websockets from a browser. MQTT.js can only use native MQTT when used with NodeJS

Comment: Do you know any broker libraries that support Web sockets in .Net?

Answer (score 2):

The next version of MQTTnet (2.5) will have support for WebSocket connections for the server via AspNetCore 2.0.

Comment: can we use websosocket now asp.net mvc?

Comment: but still can't use web-socket option in Server .Net Standard . (Not Core)

Comment: in ".Net core" all the functions are worked fine. yes, already i have started project.  i used v2.8.4. how to implement websocket option in server side?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Server#aspnet-core-integration