# MQTTnet Server using Websockets and TCP simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, mqtt, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on a MQTT Server solution using **MQTTnet** and **MQTTnet.ASPNetCore** .NET libraries. I need the server to provide a Websockets endpoint so that I can interact with it from a JavaScript application.

I have tested both using a regular **TCP-based server** as a console application and a **Websockets-based server** as a APS.Net Core 2.0 application. Both applications work fine, and I can connect to them from an MQTT client using TCP and Websockets respectively.

I was wondering if it would be possible to implement both **TCP and Websockets endpoints simultaneously**, so that I can connect TCP clients and Websockets clients that can share the topics and exchange messages.

I have tried adding some configuration options used by the TCP server when I create the Hosted Mqtt Server of the ASP.Net application:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
        .WithConnectionBacklog(100)
        .WithDefaultEndpoint()
        .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883)
        .Build();

    services.AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as I can reach the Websockets endpoint but not the TCP one.

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547658/use-mqttnet-server-with-mqtt-js-client